# Local Search phase (1) needs to start from an initialized solution

Tags: optaplanner

During Solving vehicle routing problem using Optaplanner 6.1.0 i am getting error

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local Search phase (1) needs to start from an initialized solution, but the planning variable (Customer.previousStandstill) is uninitialized for the entity

It start with solving.
[org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver] (Thread-166) Solving started: time spent (86), best score (760uninitialized/0hard/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), random (JDK with seed 0).
 but in between it throws exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local Search phase (1) needs to start from an initialized solution, but the planning variable (Customer.previousStandstill) is uninitialized for the entity (KANDIVALI).
  Initialize the solution by configuring a Construction Heuristic phase before this phase.

how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2):

when I set "unimprovedMinutesSpentLimit" in termination like this:

```
<termination>
        <unimprovedMinutesSpentLimit>5</unimprovedMinutesSpentLimit>
</termination>
```

and the CH phase doesn't finish in 5 minutes, I will get this error just after the LS phase has begun.
Seems the CH phase has exit early and not all of the Planning Entities were initialized.

So I checked the manual and set the termination condition like this

```
    <termination>
        <minutesSpentLimit>15</minutesSpentLimit>
    </termination>
```

and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Configure a Construction Heuristic before your Local Search or don't configure anything at all.

Comment: i have configured that. Its happening because of termination dynamic configuration i have provided. Currently using setTerminationConfigList and in that 2 configuration are there